# Web2py Error in redirection of URL function

Tags: jquery, view, controller, redirect, web2py

i am working on web2py for a cloud platform. I have a page where there are multiple requests that can be approved or rejected. Until a few days ago, when I clicked the Approve request button, it would successfully call the **approve_request** controller function in the controller admin.py through an ajax request. I have made no changes whatsoever, but now it redirects to a page with the following error when I click the button:

**invalid function (admin/undefined)**

Here is the code of the ajax call in jQuery:

```
function approve_selected_req(){
    var ids = [];  

    jQuery('#sortTable1 tr').has(".chcktbl:checked").each(function() {
            var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Finds the closest row <tr> 
            $tds = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)"); // Finds the 2nd <td> element
            var id = $tds.text();
            ids.push($tds.text());
            $('#out').append(ids.join('|'));
            $.ajax({
                'type': 'POST',
                'url': "{{=URL(r=request, c='admin',f='approve_request')}}",
                'data':{
                'id' : id
                },
                'success':  function(data){  alert('Approved Request: ' + id ); 
                                        }
            });
            check_resource(id);
        });
}
```

Similarly, I have a reject request function which is as follows:

```
 function reject_selected_req(){
    var ids = [];  
    jQuery('#sortTable1 tr').has(".chcktbl:checked").each(function() {

            var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Finds the closest row <tr> 
            $tds = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)"); // Finds the 2nd <td> element
            var id = $tds.text();
            ids.push($tds.text());
            $('#out').append(ids.join('|'));
            $.ajax({
                'type': 'POST',
                'url': "{{=URL(r=request, c='admin',f='reject_request')}}",
                'data':{
                'id' : id
                },
                'success':  function(data){  alert('Request Rejected: ' + id); 
                                        }
            });
            check_resource(id);
        });
}
```

The reject request call is working fine but the approve request one is not. Here is the code of the controller action functions **approve_request** and **reject_request**:

```
@check_moderator
@handle_exception
def approve_request():
    request_id=request.vars.id;
    logger.info("\nApproving request id: " + request_id + "\n");
    enqueue_vm_request(request_id);
    session.flash = 'Installation request added to queue'
    logger.debug("anmol")
    redirect(URL(c='admin', f='list_all_pending_requests'))

@check_moderator
@handle_exception
def reject_request():
    request_id=request.vars.id;
    logger.info("\nRejecting request: " + request_id + "\n");
    reject_vm_request(request_id);
    session.flash = 'Request Rejected'
    redirect(URL(c='admin', f='list_all_pending_requests'))
```

**Update**:
I am truly sorry for the delay in communication.
I have debugged the problem and the issue is somewhere in the check_resource(id) function. Here is the check_resource() code:

```
function check_resource(request_id){

var verify_url = "{{=URL('verify_vm_resource')}}";
jQuery.post(verify_url, {request_id:request_id},
    function(result){
        if(result != 'Success'){
            $('.flash').html(result).slideDown();
        }else
        {
            var link = $("#accept_"+request_id);
            window.location.href = link.attr("href");            
            console.log("Link: " + window.location.href);
        }
    }
);
return false;
```

}

In this case, the console.log prints this:"Link: https://127.0.0.1/baadal/admin/list_all_pending_requests"
And the http request displayed in the console is: GET 
https://127.0.0.1/baadal/admin/undefined

Ideally, it should have redirected to the same page but it is not doing so.

Comment: In the browser developer tools, check the network tab when you click the button. What URL is requested in the Ajax request?

Comment: Or look at the source of the generated page and check if the generated url in the js code is ok, another thing is that in my opinion, is not a good practice add part of the js code dynamically

Comment: @Anthony Thank you for the quick response. On clicking the button the URL called is https://127.0.0.1/baadal/admin/undefined but I cannot understand why it is so. Also, the function approve_request does egt called in the background and processes the request i.e. adds it to the request queue.

Comment: @Cesar Thank you for your answer. Where must I look for the URL? Also what do you mean by adding js code dynamically? Please explain.

Comment: We're missing something here. If the `approve_request` action is getting called, then the browser must at some point be making an Ajax request to that URL. Are you saying you are *subsequently* seeing another Ajax request to 127.0.0.1/baadal/admin/undefined? Since `undefined` is Javascript and not Python, presumably you have some Javascript code somewhere that is constructing that URL. We probably need to see the code for `check_resource`, and maybe `list_all_pending_requests`.

Comment: Just as @Anthony says, there must be an ajax request with a not existent url (127.0.0.1/baadal/admin/undefined), you can also right click in any part of the web (it works in almost any browser) and look an option like "see page sorce code", and look if the url is explicity generated

Comment: I mean that the js code should be placed in an external .js file, and that part of the javascript code should not be server side generated, as you are doing with the web2py URL helper, it works, but is not considered a good practise because is difficult to reuse the code in other applications (or even in other parts of the same application)

Comment: @Cesar, it seems unlikely that the /undefined URL will be found in the page source, as it is most likely being generated via Javascript (nothing on the Python side would be likely to generate the string "undefined"). Also, I wouldn't say that generating the URL via Python for use by the Javascript code is necessarily a bad practice (coding the URL manually and keeping it consistent with any URL rewrite rules could well be worse practice). However, it would probably be better to assign the URL to a Javascript variable outside of the main Javascript code and then simply refer to that variable.

Comment: @Anthony assign the url as a data attribute and write the javascript code for look to the data is the way to go, it will bring a completely independent and reusable js code, about the undefined url, you are right (I agree with you in my comment before) but there is always the option that for some nasty issue the url has been handwritten (coping js code from the wrong place, for example)